# How to make a reversed array from another array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I want to make a reversed array for another array in C.

For example:

```
int nums[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

I want "reversed" to be the reversed array of array noms

```
int reverse[6]={6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

What I have so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int nums[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
int size=sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);
int reversed[size];


for (int i=size;i>0;i--){
reversed[size-i]=nums[i];

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not actually asked a question or described a specific problem. If the code is not working as you expect run it in a debugger and step through it line by line.

Comment: For starters, what are the indices of the arrays in the first iteration of the loop? Does it look correct to you?

Comment: Your accessing `nums` out fo range. On the first iteration `i` is `size` and you fetch `nums[i]`, therefore `nums[size]`. Allowable indexes are `0..(size-1)`. Therefore, your program invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple function to reverse an array would be:

```
void reverse(int array[], int start, int end)
{
  int tmp;
  while (start < end)
  {
    tmp = array[start]; 
    array[start] = array[end];
    array[end] = tmp;
    start++;
    end--;
  }
}
```

Comment: More accurately, the function reverses a segment of an array.  It reverses an array when the start is zero and the end is the index of the last element of the array.